# Why does not ''.join(list1) work after insert a new element?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I have a list `list = ['a', 'b']`. Then I create a new list by `list1 = list.insert(0, 'c')`. After that I want to join all the strings in `list1` by `''.join(list1)`. Could you please explain why how to resolve the error `can only join an iterable`?

```
list = ['a', 'b']
list1 = list.insert(0, 'c')
''.join(list1)
```

Comment: `list.insert(0, 'c')` is a inplace opetration it does not return a new list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.insert(0, 'c')` does not return anything, so to do this you can write

```
list = ['a', 'b']
list.insert(0, 'c')
print(''.join(list))
```

Output: `'cab'`